# python substring using variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, substring

im trying to use substring method for python

```
           for i in range(len(s)):
                len1 = self.expandFromMiddle(s,i,i) 
                len2 = self.expandFromMiddle(s,i,i+1)
                len3 = max(len1,len2)
                if(len3 > end - start):
                    start = i -((len3 - 1)/2)
                    end = i + (len3/2)
        
        return s[start:end]
```

but it gives me a type error. How can I use the substring method in python by using variables?

Thank you!

Comment: Using `/` for division always returns a float in python. But you want `start` to be an int. Use `//` instead of `/`.

Comment: it is called `slice` not `substring`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using normal division (via /) that always returns data of type float. But for substring slices you need ints.
You have 2 options:

convert float to int :

```
start = i - (int((len3 - 1)/2))
end = i + (int(len3/2))
```

use integer division :

```
start = i - (int((len3 - 1)//2))
end = i + (int(len3//2))
```